# How to get the number of results from a query with pgsql in processing?

Tags: postgresql, processing

For example if we have a query like:

```
pgsql.query(SELECT * FROM table_name)
```

We can get the result by:

```
pgsql.getString("field_name");
```

How to get the result from:

```
pgsql.query(SELECT count(*) FROM table_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `count(*)` column an alias

```
pgsql.query(SELECT count(*) as the_count FROM table_name)
```

Then use whatever is the method to get a number from a column

```
pgsql.getString("the_count");
```